# Crear un patron ascii con bucles for en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, bucles

#### El usuario debe ingresar la longitud del tablero (long x long).

**Debe quedar así (long = 8):**

[image: se supone que debe estar asi U_U]

```
long = int(input(longitud))

for j in range(3*long- long + 1):
    print("* ", end="")
print()

for l in range(long):
    for i in range(3 - 2):
        for k in range(long):
            print("* ", end="")
            for j in range(3 - 2):
                print("  ", end="")
        print("* ")

    for j in range(3*long- long + 1):
        print("* ", end="")
    print()
```

**El codigo que logré, arroja:**

[image: Pero solo logro esto]

Comment: y cual es el error?, cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Supongo que quiere que se muestre el patrón de la primera imagen

Comment: Si te respondiera, estaria haciendo la tarea por ti. Mi recomendacion es que replantees el código, pues queda claro que no logra lo que te pide el ejercicio. Y si tienes un problema puntual, recurras a este foro.

Comment: Lo que neceso es que me arroje el primer patron. por más que lo intente solo logré el ultimo patron.

Comment: Lamento no poder ayudarte :c No te puede ayudar un profe particular o un compañero tuyo a resolverlo? Aun asi, es un lindo patron el que te sale c:

Comment: Si logras una sola linea, lograras todas.. piensa que la primer linea es tres espacios, tres asteriscos.. repetido 4 veces... y eso lo repetis 3 veces... y luego invertis el orden de lo que imprimis a tres astericos, tres espacios... y todo eso, lo tenes que volver a repetir 4 veces...

Comment: Entiendo tu punto. Pero ¿como seria cuando el usuario es el que ingresa la longitud del tablero?

Comment: si la longitud es 1, cual es el patron? si la longitud es 2? si es 3? es solo saber que hacer en 1, en 2, y luego repetir para lo que pida el usuario....

Comment: No es posible hacerlo sólo con `for`, almenos no si quieres que funcione para cualquier longitud. Necesariamente debes evaluar una condición en algún momentya sea con `if` o con `while`.

Comment: Ya que el usuario es el que da la longitud, lo único que debes saber es que _casilla_, o _baldosa_ estás dibujando cada vez, con esto en mente, ya solo defines que caracter imprimir, si la línea es par y la casilla es par, usas espacio, si la línea es par y la casilla es impar, usas asterisco. Para las casillas impares, inviertes el uso de los caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí cada «baldosa» tiene tres caracteres (asterisco o espacio) 
multiplica ***longitud * 3*** eso te dirá cuantas veces 
tienes que imprimir un carácter y con un contador puedes saber
si usar **asterisco** o **espacio**, por ejemplo: 
`sí ((contador mod 3) igual a 0) …`

Analiza este codigo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

long = int(input("¿Longitud del tablero? "))
caracter = " "
contador = 0

for h in range(long):
    for i in range(3):
        if (h % 2) == 0:
            caracter = " "
        else:
            caracter = "*"
        
        for j in range(long * 3):
            print(caracter, end="")
            contador = contador + 1
            
            if (contador % 3) == 0:
                contador = 0
                
                if (caracter == "*"):
                    caracter = " "
                else:
                    caracter = "*"
        print()
    if (caracter == "*"):
        caracter = " "
    else:
        caracter = "*"
print()
```

Trata de entender que se hace en cada línea, 
simplifícalo y compartelo para que otros lo entiendan.

Espero te ayude en algo.

Comment: Vamos mejor.. pero ojo, que para las "filas" impares, la logica es al reves.. asi que estamos todos esperando a que OP defina bien que es lo que tiene que imprimir y como....

Comment: de paso, mira [answer] tu respuesta se puede considerar solo un comentario...

Comment: Ok entendido! Gracias

Answer (score 2):

Bueno te voy a dar una guia de lo que debes de tomar en cuenta para realizar tu patron.

1. Según lo que quieres lograr es un patrón que sea *Si/NO*, es decir que muestre algo y luego nada, como en tu caso primero hay espacio, luego asteriscos, luego nuevamente espacios, luego nuevamente asteriscos ..., así hasta completar la longitud dada. Y esto es tanto para las coordenadas en *X* como en *Y*
2. El patrón de asteriscos debe de estar formado por una dimensión de `3x3` (o un cuadrado de `3*3`). Tanto de espacios como de asteriscos

También puedes interpretarlo como:

1. Las líneas pares comienzan con espacio, mientras que las impares no.
2. La longitud será igual a `x` contando con espacios

¿Qué puedes hacer?
Luego de haber encontrado las características para armar nuestro patrón podemos hacer varias cosas, por ejemplo:

1. podemos tener creado el cuadrado de asteriscos y el de espacios, tal que los imprimimos cuando sea correspondiente
2. Podemos tener el patrón como líneas de asteriscos `***` y espacios `'   '` e ir imprimiendo cuando sea correspondiente

> Observacion:
> El patrón es muy parecido a un tablero de ajedrez.

El código es muy sencillo, solo divide tu problema grande en problemas pequeños, no te vayas a hacer un patrón de `8x8` comienza por uno de `2x2` o `3x3`, piensa en que formas se puede hacer, ¿Cuáles son las formas de armar el patrón?, si es un patrón es por que es una serie de caracteres que se repiten.

A continuación dejo un resumen de las condiciones o requisitos del patrón

> longitud resultante: x*x
>
> long en X y Y = x
>
> Condiciones:
> lineas pares: empiezan con espacio
> lines impares: sin espacio

Comment: Gracias!!!! Ya me esta más claro.

Comment: @LuthienBtz De nada, te sugiero que intentes todo lo que puedas aplicando la lógica *correcta*, sabiendo el *¿por que funciona?* y el *¿por que no funciona?*, recuerda que si tienes dudas puedes realizar tu pregunta!

Answer (score 2):

Si piensas en un tablero más pequeño de 1x1:

```
 +--+
 | *|
 |* |
 +--+
```

Podríamos  decir que tienes dos patrones de líneas, los que empiezan en blanco y los que empiezan negros o con asteriscos, estos patrones se repiten un número de veces según el tamaño de cada celda formando filas y a su vez estas filas se repiten según la longitud del tablero.

Si generalizamos este problema, lo primero que podríamos hacer es construir los dos patrones:

```
n = 8 # Longitud del tablero
c = 3 # Tamaño de la celda

l1 = (("*" * c) + (" " * c)) * int(n/2)
l2 = ((" " * c) + ("*" * c)) * int(n/2)

print(l1)
print(l2)

***   ***   ***   ***   
   ***   ***   ***   ***
```

Apoyándonos en el funcionamiento de la multiplicación de las cadenas, construímos el patrón impar (`l1`) y el par (`l2`) todo se reduce a repetir estos según el tamaño de cada celda formando una fila y repitiendo luego el proceso por la longitud o cantidad de filas deseadas:

```
tablero = ""
for i in range(n):
  for j in range(c):
    if i % 2:
      tablero = tablero + l1 + "\n" 
    else:
      tablero = tablero + l2 + "\n"
```

Por cierto, si no te asusta el anidado de paréntesis, otra solución podría ser partir de la forma en la que en código anterior hemos creado los patrones para los dos modelos de filas, y generalizar a todo el tablero, y sin usar un solo ciclo `for` explícito:

```
n = 8 # Longitud del tablero
c = 3 # Tamaño de la celda
b = " " * c # blancos
a = "*" * c # asteriscos

tablero = (((((b + a) * int(n/2)) + "\n") * c) + ((((a + b) * int(n/2)) + "\n") * c)) * int(n/2)
```